# Collection initializer doesn't work with collection definition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collections, initializer

I tried merging a collection definition with a collection initializer in C#, but failed to initialize the collection. See the codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ListEX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> sList = new List<string>()
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D",
    };


    void Start()
    {
        sList.Add("X");
        sList.Add("Y");

        string str = "";
        foreach (string i in sList)
        {
            str += i;
        }
        print(str);
    }
```

The output of **str** was "XY" instead of "ABCDXY", which confuzed me a lot. The same problem happened to arrays and dictionaries when I tried them out.

I assume I made a mistake in the scope of the collection initializer. So, I tried separating the collection initializer from the collection definition.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ListEX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> sList;


    void Start()
    {
        sList = new List<string>()
        {
            "A", "B", "C", "D",
        };
        sList.Add("X");
        sList.Add("Y");

        string str = "";
        foreach (string i in sList)
        {
            str += i;
        }
        print(str);
    }
```

The output of **str** was "ABCDXY", which met my expectation. My thought seems to be proved right. However, I cannot still explain the principle of how C# works with this.

I'd appreciate it if someone can give me an explanation.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the object and call the `Start()` method? How do you call it anyway since it is marked as private? Maybe you call a `sList.Clear()` before you call `Start()`

Comment: @SomeBody It's Unity. `Start()` is a method that's there by convention, and seemingly called through reflection: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: I don't know Unity well, but I believe it has its very own opinion on how to initialize MonoBehaviour-derived objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Unity MonoBehaviour script, by default public fields (`sList` in this question) can be edited in a window called [inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html), the values of these fields will be [deserialized](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) on initial, C# has nothing todo with it, that's why you get an empty list when `Start` runs.

If you want to test the collection initializer and avoid being affected by serialization, you can change the access modifier to private, or use the `NonSerialized` attribute.

```
public class ListEX : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string> sList = new List<string>()
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D",
    };

    [System.NonSerialized]
    public List<string> sList2 = new List<string>()
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D",
    };
}
```

BTW the same problem should not happen to `Dictionary<K,V>` because it is not a serializable type to Unity, if there is a problem with the dictionary type, please provide the code with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that is to the point! I tried coding this in a .NET console app and it worked well. As you said, C# has nothing to do with the problem.